# Is there an API call to start a scan for hardware devices

Tags: .net, windows, winapi, bluetooth

Related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2145207/rescan-device-tree-for-hardware-changes-during-driver-installation), but... is it possible to trigger via API a new hardware device scan? I have a serial port Bluetooth device that I'm pairing automatically via API calls with [32feet.net .NET Bluetooth](http://inthehand.co.uk/content/32feet.aspx), which works quite nicely.  While i can query for the serial services in the scanning of the device, the COM ports don't show up in the Bluetooth Devices dialog's COM Ports tab.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Related to [Programmatically uninstall a device in windows device manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2175601/programmatically-uninstall-a-device-in-windows-device-manager)

My answer from there:

> To force the 'scan for hardware
>   changes' checkout "[How To Force
>   Reenumeration of a Device Tree From an
>   Application](https://web.archive.org/web/20140111225728/http://support.microsoft.com/kb/259697)" the sample there
>   shows how to force the entire tree to
>   be re-enumerated.

Answer (score 12):

Not sure if this will help your overall problem but this should answer the question in your first sentence.

I originally did something like this using Nullsoft's NSIS installer a few years ago.

If you just want to trigger a vanilla hardware scan you can use the following code (provided in C# per the .net tag in this question):

**This is the wrapper class for the P/Invoke functions**

```
public static class Win32Api
{
    public const int CM_LOCATE_DEVNODE_NORMAL = 0x00000000;
    public const int CM_REENUMERATE_NORMAL = 0x00000000;
    public const int CR_SUCCESS = 0x00000000;

    [DllImport("CfgMgr32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
    public static extern int CM_Locate_DevNodeA(ref int pdnDevInst, string pDeviceID, int ulFlags);

    [DllImport("CfgMgr32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
    public static extern int CM_Reenumerate_DevNode(int dnDevInst, int ulFlags);
}
```

**This is a sample of how to use them**

```
int pdnDevInst = 0;

        if (Win32Api.CM_Locate_DevNodeA(ref pdnDevInst, null, Win32Api.CM_LOCATE_DEVNODE_NORMAL) != Win32Api.CR_SUCCESS)
            throw new Exception("something...");

        if (Win32Api.CM_Reenumerate_DevNode(pdnDevInst, Win32Api.CM_REENUMERATE_NORMAL) != Win32Api.CR_SUCCESS)
            throw new Exception("something else...");
```

I just quickly translated this from the MSDN C++ docs and tested it in a spike so I know it works but it's not production quality.  Also, if you care about the specific return codes you can look them up in cfgmgr32.h.

Comment: didn't look at the previous answers but just in case you thought I copied here the original version I did in NSIS: http://forums.winamp.com/showthread.php?t=192348

Comment: Also, mine is in C# and the MS sample is in classic VB.

Comment: Works like a charm. Notice: YOU HAVE TO RUN THE WINAPI CALLS WITH ADMINISTRATIVE RIGHTS! Tested on Windows 8 x64

Answer (score 1):

Does my answer at the following help? [How can I find out a COM port number of a bluetooth device in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2085179/how-can-i-find-out-a-com-port-number-of-a-bluetooth-device-in-c/2119058#2119058)

In brief use `System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.GetPortNames()` or WMI to list the serial ports, e.g. PowerShell command:

```
C:\> Get-WmiObject -query "select DeviceID,PNPDeviceID from Win32_SerialPort"
```

Which can also be done in code.

Answer (score 1):

Just found [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3146370/programatically-restart-usb-device-in-windows) that also may solve my issue or others that find this question.