# Can DevCon notify when a driver is finished installing after a rescan?

Tags: installation, driver, wdk, inf, device-manager

I am trying to install a driver during a windows-setup project.

The first step I do is to copy the INF file and preinstall the driver.

`SetupCopyOEMInf(infFile, null, 1, 0, null, 0, 0, null);`

This correctly preinstalls the driver, but the device is not ready to use until a hardware rescan is done in Device Manager. I want to automate this as well. I have tried using [the setupapi.dll to invoke the hardware rescan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2181525/is-there-an-api-call-to-start-a-scan-for-hardware-devices), but it was not always successful for me. Using devcon.exe rescan always forces the hardware rescan, but it is a synchronous command, and it returns before the device is finished installing. Is there any way to get a return result after the hardware scan completes and the driver is successfully installed?

Thanks,

Misha

**Edit**

Here is my working code:

```
    public const UInt32 CR_SUCCESS = 0;
    public const UInt64 CM_REENUMERATE_SYNCHRONOUS = 1;
    public const UInt64 CM_LOCATE_DEVNODE_NORMAL = 0;

    [DllImport("setupapi.dll")]
    public static extern bool SetupCopyOEMInf(
      string SourceInfFileName,
      string OEMSourceMediaLocation,
      int OEMSourceMediaType,
      int CopyStyle,
      string DestinationInfFileName,
      int DestinationInfFileNameSize,
      int RequiredSize,
      string DestinationInfFileNameComponent
      );

    [DllImport("cfgmgr32.dll")]
    public static extern int CM_Locate_DevNode_Ex(ref IntPtr deviceHandle, int deviceId, uint flags, IntPtr machineHandle);

    [DllImport("cfgmgr32.dll")]
    public static extern int CM_Reenumerate_DevNode_Ex(IntPtr devInst, UInt64 flags);

    [DllImport("cfgmgr32.dll")]
    public static extern int CMP_WaitNoPendingInstallEvents(UInt32 timeOut);

    static void Main() {
      bool success = SetupCopyOEMInf(infFile, null, 1, 0, null, 0, 0, null);

      if(!success) {
        throw new Exception("Error installing driver");
      }

      success = RescanAllDevices();

      if (!success) {
        throw new Exception("Error installing driver");
      }
    }

    public static bool RescanAllDevices() {
      int ResultCode = 0;
      IntPtr LocalMachineInstance = IntPtr.Zero;
      IntPtr DeviceInstance = IntPtr.Zero;
      UInt32 PendingTime = 30000;

      ResultCode = CM_Locate_DevNode_Ex(ref DeviceInstance, 0, 0, LocalMachineInstance);
      if (CR_SUCCESS == ResultCode) {
        ResultCode = CM_Reenumerate_DevNode_Ex(DeviceInstance, CM_REENUMERATE_SYNCHRONOUS);
        ResultCode = CMP_WaitNoPendingInstallEvents(PendingTime);
      }
      return ResultCode == CR_SUCCESS;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the code! However, if the driver installation failed previously and a dummy driver was installed, then only rebooting the system installs the new driver. So, reboot seems to be the safest method. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14937261/equivalent-of-scan-for-hardware-changes-in-device-manager-doesnt-work-after-f

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source for devcon is available in the WDK.  It's in the src\setup\devcon directory.  The logic for the rescan command is in the cmdRescan function in cmds.cpp.  It would be a simple matter to copy that logic into your own code and make sure it doesn't return immediately.

Comment: Devcon does not solve this issue: it uses an async rescan

Comment: @ColinJensen You didn't read my answer beyond the first sentence, did you? I said the source was available and it could easily be modified to be synchronous.